# MySQL - query to return NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have the following code:

```sql
SELECT q25, (
(
AVG( q1 ) + AVG( q2 ) + AVG( q3 ) ) /3 ) AS Overall
FROM t_results
WHERE brand =  'XYZ'
AND DATE =  'MAY2012'
GROUP BY q25
ORDER BY Overall 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

If there is no data found by the query phpmyadmin returns the following message (which is quite correct):

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0178 sec )
```

However, what I'd like is to actually return a `NULL` value, is this possible?  I appreciate this might not be best practise but I'm working with inherited code and this might be the simplist and quickest route to a solution.

Thanks as always,

H.

Comment: @MvG - as a matter of interest, what did you edit?

Comment: Click on the link after the word *edited*, and you'll see the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11629211/revisions). I first changed the syntax highlighting, and then the tags. This has nothing to do with php, and selecting the sql tag will ensure sql highlighting by default, for answers as well. Plus give you more suitable experts to look at this question.

Comment: @MvG - cheers, much appreciated.  Like the second option as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a table with exactly one row. Then you can use left join to achieve the desired `NULL` result.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dummy (d TINYINT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO dummy SET d = 1;

SELECT q25,
       ( ( AVG( q1 ) + AVG( q2 ) + AVG( q3 ) ) /3 ) AS Overall
FROM dummy LEFT JOIN t_results
  ON brand = 'XYZ'
 AND DATE = 'MAY2012'
GROUP BY q25
ORDER BY Overall DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You can also replace the dummy table with a subquery:

```sql
SELECT q25,
       ( ( AVG( q1 ) + AVG( q2 ) + AVG( q3 ) ) /3 ) AS Overall
FROM (SELECT 1) AS dummy LEFT JOIN t_results
  ON brand =  'XYZ'
 AND DATE =  'MAY2012'
GROUP BY q25
ORDER BY Overall DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Tested this via [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5ded/1), where you can also experiment with alternatives.

The conditions selecting the result, which used to be in the `WHERE` clause, now have to go into the `ON` clause. Otherwise the left join would produce non-`NULL` rows which would be removed by the `WHERE`, instead of generating a single `NULL` row if no matching row could be found. If there were no `WHERE` conditions in the original query, `ON 1` could be used to express `any row matches`.

Comment: A very elegant solution :-) - Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UNION` combined with a `LIMIT` to supply the `NULL` values:

```
(SELECT q25,
        (AVG(q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3))/3 AS Overall
 FROM t_results
 WHERE brand = 'XYZ'
 AND DATE = 'MAY2012'
 GROUP BY q25
 ORDER BY Overall DESC
 LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT NULL, NULL)
LIMIT 1;
```

This only works when you know that the first query will never yield more than one result, though. Which is the case here, so this might be the best solution for you, but the approach given in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11629787/1468366) is more general.

There is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5ded/13) for this to experiment with.

Comment: I think that this is actually much more elegant than the query that I scrawled out. +1

Comment: Yep, even nicer! :-)  However, already implemented the first.  Would you like me to tick this one instead???

Comment: @Homer_J, seeing as I believe the answer you accepted to be more general than this one here, I'd prefer the tick mark to remain where it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `coalesce()` function can be used to return the first non-null value from a number of comma separated columns or strings. The values/columns are evaluated left to right, so if you want to pop a string into the arguments that isn't null, make sure you place it to the right of the columns that you are testing against.

```
select
    coalesce(
    (
    SELECT
        q25
    FROM 
        t_results
    WHERE 
        brand =  'XYZ'
        AND DATE =  'MAY2012'
    GROUP BY 
        q25
    LIMIT 1
    ), 'null') as q25,
    coalesce(
    (
    SELECT 
        ((AVG( q1 ) + AVG( q2 ) + AVG( q3 ) ) /3 ) AS Overall
    FROM t_results
    WHERE 
        brand =  'XYZ'
        AND DATE =  'MAY2012'
    LIMIT 1
    ), 'null') as Overall
from 
    t_results
group by 
    1, 2;
```

If you don't have data that matches your `where` clause, this will return `null, null` as a row.

Comment: Cool... a query... anything else?

Comment: @fluffeh - cheers for that - think there was an error, should it be 'null'?  When I changed that I get the message 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'

Comment: @Homer_J Yeah, sorry about that, also forgot to `group by` in the query. Try this :)

Comment: @rlemon The question posted a query and asked for an answer. What is wrong with giving a query as an answer?

Comment: @fluffeh - cheers for the reply, sadly still getting the same message...can't see what's happening :-(

Comment: Looking at it again, I may have have had a little bit too much wine. You are querying for two columns in your query. Let me rewrite that for you. Will edit in a sec.

Comment: @Homer_J Can you give that a whirl?

Comment: I entered a dummy table in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5ded/1) to check my own answer. Feel free to give yours a try there as well. Currently it does not work.

Comment: It seems that the group by was wrong in the second coalesce. I have updated it (my own test table was working with a modified query). I have saved another [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5ded/9/0) with the query I have updated this answer with.

Comment: When the table *does* yield results, your query gives the wrong result. That's because the AVG will not be for this `q25` only, but for all groups.

Comment: @MvG I have the exact same conditions in each subquery. How would that yield a different result. Either Q25 is returned and the AVG is correct or neither row is returned and the query will output `null,null` in one row.

Comment: @Fluffeh generally a small explanation of the code should be provided.  However it looks like you put a note on the function used and why. cheers.

Comment: Have a look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5ded/11). You compute the second column as 3.4, which is the result of *all* five rows matching the original WHERE clause. The correct result, however, would be 5.5, computed from the two rows with `q25=2`. In original query, the `GROUP BY` imposes an added condition that the `AVG` is computed only within each group. That condition is lacking in your second subquery.

Comment: @MvG Yes, you are right, the limit 1 clause isn't being evaluated in my second subquery. Looks like the OP accepted your answer though. I should stop trawling for questions when I am exhausted methinks.